# PySpark toPandas faster alternative

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

Is there a faster alternative to convert a PySpark dataframe to a pandas dataframe? I do have "spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled" set to "true", but it is still taking hours to convert a dataframe. I have also tried writing to parquet from spark and then reading it back in using arrow, but writing is taking hours as well.

Bonus, is there any way to have a spark process fail quickly? Sometimes, in the above situations, I find out hours later that the reason the conversion took so long was because of a schema datatype mismap, if only I could have not waited hours to get that failure.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, there're a few questions you should ask before trying to convert a database from spark to pandas

-Why? Is it a specific need? To train a model for example, or is it to make an analysis?
-What's the size of the dataframe? (2 million+ rows or something like that?)

Because depending on the scale of your dataframe it's not even viable or possible to convert to pandas. So I would **HIGHLY** suggest that you either work directly with spark (there are many models available in spark's mllib) or if using pandas is a **must** then filter your database, work with smaller data.

Also, here's a link that might help clarifying why it's not a good a idea to convert to pandas depending on the size of your dataframe, but it's pretty much because of spark lazy, one of the main reasons to why it's possible to work with large data, something pandas does not have saving everything on memory:
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-spark-dataframe-and-pandas-dataframe/#:~:text=Complex%20operations%20are%20easier%20to,a%20large%20amount%20of%20data](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-spark-dataframe-and-pandas-dataframe/#:%7E:text=Complex%20operations%20are%20easier%20to,a%20large%20amount%20of%20data).